# How to resolve CORS issues with testcafe for file:// and https:// XHRs

Tags: testing, cors, automated-tests, web-testing, testcafe

TestCafe devs: Thanks for creating a great, easy to use product!

I'm using testcafe to do full end-to-end tests on my electron app, which is sending XHRs with most endpoint URLs having the `file://` scheme and some others an API that we control.

I fixed the CORS issues (testcafe proxy was responding with the 222 code) with the `file://` URLs by starting up the Http-server npm package with `--cors` turned on.

My current problem is that when my app sends the XHR to the API, nothing I seem to do resolves the problem. I'm **not** looking to mock the API requests. When not running my app inside testcafe instances, both `file://` and API requests have no issues.

**Is there a (straightforward) way to solve this? (Also, is there a similar solution for the `file://` requests without having to create a webserver?)** I'm assuming this issue is common, and I have looked thru the Github issues for both testcafe and testcafe-hammerhead as well as the Recipes page. I've also tried to create a request hook, but I'm still getting the 222 response code.

Here is my custom hook:

```
class MyHook extends RequestHook {
  constructor(requestFilterRules) {
    super(requestFilterRules, {includeHeaders: true, includeBody: true});
  }
  onRequest(event) {
    event.requestOptions.headers['Origin'] = 'file://';
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that all I had to do was change the `Origin:` header to something that my API accepts, per the above code. (I'm guessing that the presence/absence of the includeHeaders/include body properties or the response method in the above code do not have an effect here, but I'm not sure.)

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like a bug for me. Could you please post an example of the endpoint URLs?

Comment: Example endpoint *before* using local webserver: file:///C:/Project/src/js/modules/settings/views/home.code.page.html

Comment: Also, when I console'd out `event` per my code above, I see that `_requestInfo` has both a lowercase `origin:` header of 'file:///C:/Project/src/index.html' and an uppercase `Origin:` header of 'file://'.

Comment: I took a stab at a fix without doing much testing, and added

    this.headers['access-control-allow-origin'] = '*';

to the `_onRequest` method in file-request.js around line 65. I noticed that the browser appears to do this for normal `file://` requests. This is fixing my first issue of requests from `file://` urls to `file://` urls. I am still looking into fixing CORS issues from `file://` urls to `https://` urls.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Please create a new bug report and provide a sample app that can be used to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md.